# Spring Boot can't access REST Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a simple problem - SpringBootApplication doesn't see my controller - what's more weird - only one of three.

I have UserController, WalletController and DashboardController - this one is not visible for my application.

What I have already done is:

1. Every package with controller is under the main package, where my **SpringBootApplication.class** is,
2. I tried annotate main **SpringBootApplication.class** with *@ComponentScan* both with basePackages and basePackageClasses,
3. There is no other beans - which should be annotated *@Component*, I removed them and moved methods to my **DashboardService.class**

This is my controller, which is not visible:
[DashboardController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdO9y.png)

And this is my package structure(seems to be right):  [Package Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS2jx.png)

Thank You for help!

EDIT:

It might be important, that I use the third-party api to get the data I need

In that methods I use **url**:

```
    private String getNbpJson(String url) {
        return new RestTemplate().getForObject(url, String.class);
    }

    private CurrentRateDTO getCurrentExchangeRate(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);

        String code = node.get("code").toString();
        String date = node.get("rates").get(0).get("effectiveDate").toString();

        double bid = node.get("rates").get(0).get("bid").asDouble();
        double ask = node.get("rates").get(0).get("ask").asDouble();

        return new CurrentRateDTO(code, date, bid, ask);
    }
```

And then in ExchangeService this is my **url**

```
@Service
public class ExchangeRateService implements IExchangeRateService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExchangeRateService.class);

    private String NBP_CURRENT_RATE_URL = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/c/eur/2020-12-11/?format=json";
```

What's more... when I move methods from *DashboardController* to *WalletController* (which works)

Another thing that I have found out is that only methods, which make use of the third-party api don't work.
Basically, I retrieve data from the url above - I get the specific fields, create an objects with filled fields.

May it be a problem with retrieving data from the third-party and then implementing it in my app?

I have no more ideas for now...

Comment: By default if there is only one `public` constructor in a bean it will be autowired by Spring with constructor injection, no need for explicit `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: Have you tried `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"pl.agn.exchange"})`?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried all that things related to scanning packages - thus I have no green idea what can be wrong and why is that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your controller is registered but you type a slightly different url. Try this property `logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation: TRACE`

and check on application startup if the controller is registered under some other url.

Try to add this to your controller

```
@RestController()   
@RequestMapping("exchangerates")
```

Comment: That is interesting... I left my Controller annotation look like `@RestController("/exchangerates)`, but the property, that You showed me displays this: `p.a.e.d.DashboardController:
 {GET /rate/{currencyCode}}: getCurrentRate(String)`

Comment: that's what i thought when I saw your controller path ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I probably found out the problem... Before I have 3 controllers:

```
@RestController("/api")
public class UserController {}

@RestController("/wallets")
public class WalletController {}

@RestController("/exchangerates")
public class DashboardController {}
```

I changed the above to

```
@RestController("/api")
public class UserController {}

@RestController
public class WalletController {}

@RestController
public class DashboardController {}
```

So, basically I removed base ?endpoint? for each controller and now it works... It seems like basic endpoints in three *RestControllers* is too much and the third one is not available, but I don't know is it truth (I bet that it's not).

Why that happened then, can anybody explain that behaviour of controllers?
Thank You for explanantion.

Comment: check my updated answer above with another annotation.